# How can I stop the torus minor radius default from changing (if I even can)?

Tags: mesh, dimensions

When I add a new torus mesh and change the minor radius, any subsequent toruses I add have that same minor radius instead of the original default. Can that be stopped and if so, how? Pls and ty!

Comment: you can right click on the value and > Reset to Default Value, but imho Blender lacks a reset function

Answer (score 1):

As moonboots wrote, you can right click -> reset to default value or just delete the value in the field and press TAB.

Comment: wow didn't know the tab thing

Comment: i have the same "wow" effect a few times a day here ;) so much to learn and so little time... ;)